# Use different IP address for every loop in running iMacros script

Tags: loops, proxy, ip, imacros

Can anyone help me with the iMacros? This will be my first time that i will use this. I need to create a script to visit a certain website but for each visit IP address should change for the website to count it as a unique visitor.

Here's what i have so far:

```
URL GOTO=http://sampleWebsite.com
WAIT SECONDS=10
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES 
PROXY ADDRESS=192.168.4.5:80 
BYPASS=http://sampleWebsite.com
```

I'm really not sure about the PROXY ADDRESS and BYPASS script part.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you need to change your ip address each loop?

Comment: Yes, that's what i need but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: That depends on your os, and your network configuration. Are they statically allocated? DHCP? Also, what the website sees is your public ip, and that is defined by your ISP

Comment: OS is windows. DHCP. What i need is an automation of accessing a website but the website should recognize the access as a unique visitor which would only happen if every visit it will be using a different IP address. For the automation of accessing a website i can use iMacros but i dont know how to change the IP address used for every loop of the iMacros script.

Comment: You can't. Not practically. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.
Your IP address is a property of your computer, not your browser.

Typically it is allocated dynamically via DHCP, but could be set statically via eg control panel.

In the DHCP case, you could in theory release the Ip address, and *hope* the DHCP server allocates a different one
 *hint: it probably wont*.

In the static case, modification typically requires user interaction and administration permission.

However, assuming this website is public, and not on the local network, then it doesn't matter. The Ip address the website sees is your public IP,  and this is set by the ISP. You have no control over this.

By the way, IP address is a terrible way of detecting unique visitors, as it doesn't allow for large corporate environments where hundreds/thousands of unique users will share one external IP.

It is more likely that the website would use additional information, for instance cookies, user agent strings etc. You might have better results if you modify the user agent string, and clear cookies

Comment: Actually there's a mobile browser(Puffin browser) that changes its IP Address whenever user would use "Reconnect to Server" which is a special feature of the browser. I was thinking if ever there would be a counterpart in desktop or if there would be an easy work around.

Comment: If you think about it, you will see that the browser cannot be changing its IP address. Because it is not a property of the browser, but the computer it is running on. It _could_ potentially be selecting one of many proxy servers to connect via, but this would still be a limited pool, and the proxy server would need to be on the internet, rather than on the local network infrastructure.